# Use CMake's ExternalProject_Add to clone git repository without building it

Tags: cmake, eigen

I want CMake to git clone a header only library without building it.
I tried:

```
ExternalProject_Add(eigen
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror.git
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}
        GIT_SHALLOW 1)
```

But that builds the external project.
How to git clone without building?

Comment: `set_target_properties(eigen PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)` doesn't work.

Comment: Please amend the original question by [edit]ing it and avoid adding crucial context in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html), you need to:

1. Set the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` parameter as an empty string (i.e. `""`) in order to stop the CMake configuration (the project is assumed to be CMake-base by default).
2. Set the `BUILD_COMMAND` parameter as an empty string to disable the build step.
3. Set the `INSTALL_COMMAND` parameter as an empty string to force the install step to do nothing.

However, if there are no complicated conditions for the inclusion of Eigen, i.e. it is always a required component for your project, you might need to consider the use of [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (this might be a better approach even if Eigen is not a mandatory requirement).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this tomorrow.